# Dynamics AX 2012 installing error

Tags: sql, sql-server, axapta

I'm trying to install Dynamics AX 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and I have problem when install Application Object Server (AOS) as below.

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Please help me out if you have any solution.
Thank you.

> An error occurred during setup of Application Object Server (AOS)
>   MicrosoftDynamicsAX at port 2712. The following error/warning
>   occurred:Cannot find the object 'UTILIDELEMENTS', because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permission. Cannot find the object
>   'UTILELEMENTS', because it does not exist or you do not have
>   permission. Cannot find the object 'UTILMODELS', because it does not
>   exist or you do not have permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 System Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11094) you have to slipstream your installation with [CU9](https://mbs2.microsoft.com/Knowledgebase/KBDisplay.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;3092626).